# New Drupal 7 Install - No Admin Access

Tags: 7

I installed Drupal 7.4 through the interface on GreenGeeks. I am not a developer, more of a web designer/manager. The site installed fine, but when I login with the admin credentials, I am not presented with any admin functionality or options, just a generic view of the site. I tried following other instructions found on drupal.org that suggested resetting the admin password using myphpadmin, which I tried, but received an error message that the users file for my database had not been created. Can anyone offer some suggested solutions?

Comment: Sounds like you have a very, very old Drupal 7 install. The latest is actually Drupal 8, but the latest Drupal 7 version is 7.41 (37 versions newer than your 7.4). If I were in your shoes, I would try to install drush and use it's "drush uli" function to give you a fresh "log me in to reset my password" link. If that's a no-go, you could try to go to /user/password and have it send you a new password via email.

Comment: Also, if you can login, then you may not see the admin screen. You can force the admin screen by going to [yoursite]/admin and see what you see. If you see an access denied then you are not an administrator and that's a whole other bag of worms.

Comment: Try installing again. In phpmyadmin select all your tables and delete them. Then go to `yourwebsite.com/install.php`